# Screen selector on initial launch in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Let me explain first.
I have three screens in my app. These are **MyHome.dart**,  **OtherHome.dart** and **Selector.dart**.
I want to launch **Selector** screen on the initial launch. In the Selector screen, there are two options to users. One is MyHome and another is OtherHome. After the first launch, the app will always open the last selected screen by the user on the first launch. What will be the right code for this?

**Main.dart**:

```
import 'selector.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Selector(),
  ));
}
```

**Selector.dart**:

```
import 'package:device_monitor/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home.dart';
import 'myhome.dart';

class Selector extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHome()),
              );
            },
            child: Text('My Device'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 30),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()),
              );
            },
            child: Text('Others Device'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a shared preference or database to save the screen the user selects, do you need a code to understand my point?

Comment: Yes please. I need an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a code that can help you:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Selector(),
  ));
}
```

You need to get **sharedpreferences** package, here's a [link](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

```
class Selector extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SelectorState createState() => _SelectorState();
}

class _SelectorState extends State<Selector> {
  
  bool pageReady = false;

  /// This checks the whether page has been selected earlier,
  /// should be placed in an initstate function
  _checkPages() async {
    SharedPreferences local = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if(local.getString('page-selected') != null){
      if(local.getString('page-selected') == "1"){
        //navigate to MyHome

        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHome()),
        );

      } else {
        //Navigate to Home
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()),
        );
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        pageReady = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _checkPages();
  }

  savePage(String type) async {
    if(type == "1"){
      SharedPreferences local = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      local.setString('page-selected', type);
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHome()),
      );
    } else {
      SharedPreferences local = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      local.setString('page-selected', type);
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: ( context ) => Home()),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: pageReady ? Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              savePage("1");
            },
            child: Text('My Device'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 30),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: ()  {
              savePage("2");
            },
            child: Text('Others Device'),
          ),
        ],
      ) : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomeState createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}


class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
```

So, I changed `Selector()` to a stateful widget and used an `initState()` to check if the user already selected a page previously, if yes, it routes the user to that page else it opens the selector page and once the user selects a page I save the page in session also with the `savePage()` function.

Comment: Thanks, to do this for me. but there are some problems with your code. This increases the app startup time and the selector page is shown for some time on each startup. and then it goes to the last selected page.

Comment: Then you can remove the checkPage from initState, create a loader, wherein that time, you can do the page check simple.

Comment: Also, you cannot expect a lesser or same startup time if you want to perform a function in-between. So decide which you want to do. and please mark my answer as correct because you did not add start up time constraints in your question.

Comment: how can I create a loader?

Comment: Welcome friend, you can connect with me on twitter, https://twitter.com/samuelezedi any time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217216/discussion-between-santo-shakil-and-samezedi).